# Watson Text-to-Speech Forwarding error: Load balancer does not have available server for client

Tags: ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

Recently I have been getting this 500 error from the Watson Text-to-Speech service. It was working fine a few months ago.

I'm calling it with the Watson Developer Cloud Java SDK and originally I thought I was just using an out-of-date version. Upon updating the SDK, I got a more informative error with the URL it was using to call the service.

https://stream-s.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?Test&voice=en-US_AllisonVoice&accept=audio%2Fwav

Opening this with a web browser will display the following error description:

```
RibbonCommandTextToSpeech failed and no fallback available. null com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: CHUCK-***********-457 Load balancer does not have available server for client: CHUCK-***********-457
```

So it seems to be a temporary problem on Watson's side but since this has been persistent for several days I'm wondering if I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Since the error is persistent and it seems to indicate an issue with the load balancer, you should probably open a Bluemix support ticket at https://support.ng.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/

Comment: I found it seems to be this particular server (stream-s) no longer works as `https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?Test&voice=en-US_AllisonVoice&accept=audio%2Fwav` does

Comment: Thanks for following up. I'll notify the Watson DevOps team.

Comment: `stream-s` is the staging non-public service. I'm assuming @cjxd is an IBM so I think we should remove this question